When parsing XML in Python, why can I assign my LXML element.text to a variable and print it, but when I try to append it to a list it is empty?
I am trying to parse an XML file and need to get text out of it. I can get it to print fine but am not able to store it properly.
Image showing where #text lives.
text_list = []

for relation in properties:
    text = relation.text
    print(text)
    text_list.append({
        'text':text
    })

This code prints the desired text, but then the list does not store the text properly.

Please provide an xml example and a minimal working example , include your import statements.
